# UK Visa for a terminally ill person

Tags: uk

My father intends to travel to the UK on a standard visitor visa to go and visit my sister who is married in the UK. He has been to the UK twice before and both times he was issued a visa with no issues whatsoever. When he travelled the previous times he was an abled person but this time around he is disabled. He is an amputee on one leg and even tho he has a prosthesis leg he is unable to walk normally and will require a wheelchair during the journey. On top of that he has kidney issues meaning that he might have to go on dialysis sooner or later. My mother, brother, sister and niece will accompany him. Most of the things he can do on his own and as such doesn't require a carer.

Can he be denied a visa on grounds that he is a disabled and/or a terminally ill person?

Comment: Nope that alone is not a justification to refuse a visa.

Comment: Being accompanied by so many members of the family may count against him

Answer (score 4):

He might get refused entry even with a visa if it appears he is coming to the UK to get NHS treatment. He would need to demonstrate that he has very substantial funds to cover the possible need for private care.

Dialysis costs something like £300 per session. 3 sessions per week is standard but new patients may need fewer sessions initially.

The fact of being an amputee is no issue.

Disregarding visas and costs, he may find the trip very strenuous (some of my elderly relatives really hate long haul). You should consider having your sister visit him as an alternative.